Metrics for short lived Flink jobs
I'm launching a job (automatically detected as batch) that reads a csv (3 records) and outputs the same content to Kafka. At the end of this job, which takes about 3s to run, I need to get some metrics, including custom ones.
Problem is that no metrics are reported until the internal is reached. I'm using a custom reporter that uses Prometheus push gateway and I've even called .report() on .close(). Still no metrics are showing.
Other jobs, long-lived, are working just fine.
Am I missing something or this something that is not supported? Is there a way to force metrics to be reported at the end of each job even if they didn't reach interval?
Works: I've called Thread.sleep(ms more than reporter interval) on one of the mappers that adds a custom metric
Works: Calling .report() when .notifyOfRemovedMetric(). This is because when registry is shutting down, it calls this for all reporters. The caller is the AbstractMetricGroup close method.

I would call into question your need for the metrics. Relying on metrics to get mission critical data out of a Flink job is an abuse of the metrics system -- which isn't designed with exactly-once guarantees in mind. It might be better to have another sink that receives the reporting info currently being collected as metrics.

A sink , as a side output, would do it and it's probably what I'll end up doing. However, instead of 3 records I could be doing the 1 billion row challenge in Flink and want to know its throughput. I understand that metrics, during long lived jobs are a non-issue. But for some data integration solutions that just get data from one place to another, which is debatable if Flink is a good fit for this (I think local does a great job), this would be mission critical.
Flushing the metric system to push reporters before the job finishes would give a more accurate overview over the job execution.

If I want to measure throughput and I add a function after source and another before sink, can I assume that Flink's backpressure mechanism will make sure that the functions are impacted, therefore impacting the metric, if Sink is slow?
I believe that's the overall behavior. So the overall throughput of a Job would be given by the meter right before the sink. (Source -> Function (source metrics) -> Some other function -> Function (sink metrics) -> Sink

Yes, that's right. This will especially be true if the sink metrics function is chained to the sink, but even if there's a network connection between them, the network will only have a small, fixed sized buffer, so any slow down in the sink will quickly affect the function.

However, every Flink operator automatically provides a bunch of performance metrics, including throughput. Perhaps you can get what you want directly from the sink w/o implementing any custom metrics.
